# SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0 in python

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentation

I'm getting the error:

`SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0`

When I'm running the code below:

```
# coding=utf-8
from PIL import Image
 
img = Image.open("img.png")
```

I have tried to load different images with different formats (png, jpg, jpeg). I have tried using different versions of the Pillow library. I have also tried running it using python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was related to a fake space found in the third line (the empty one). It is a character that looks like a space but is actually something else which is not detected by python. By removing this character the error disappeared. The character is this:

Comment: Why do characters like this even exist?